# Lists for validation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to validate an input by using a list that holds the strings that are valid inputs but I can't seem to get it to work correctly, any help?

```
choice = ["A","a","B","b"]
def main():
    test = input()
    if validate(test):
        print("Entered a")
    else:
        print("did not enter a")

def validate(val):
    try: 
        val = choice.index[1]
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True
main()
```

Comment: did you mean choice.index[val]?

Comment: I suspect it should be `choice.index(val)` (with parens, not brackets, and looking for `val`, not assigning to it). But that idiotic bare `except:` (NEVER USE BARE EXCEPT!) is masking the problem. If the except were targeted to the `ValueError` only, it wouldn't mask the `TypeError` using brackets raises. Of course, it's still a pointless way to test (`return val in choice` being correct and simpler), but that's why the original code breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?  This will check the input up against members of `val`.  If the entry is in `vals`, it will accept it.

```
vals = ["a","b","c"]
def main():
    test = input()
    if validate(test):
        print("Valid entry")
    else:
        print("did not enter valid info")
def validate(val):
    for i in vals:
        if val == i:
            return True
    return False
main()
```

I'm slightly confused by your question, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you, sorry I'm new to python so this probably should've been relatively simple

Answer (score 3):

No need for an exception in validate, just check if the list contains the element by using the `in` operator:

```
def validate(val):
    if val in choice: # checks if the value is in the list.
        return True
```

No need for an else clause in `validate()` either since the function will return `None` which will evaluate to `False`.

---

To make this better, just return the element (which will evaluate to `True` again):

```
choice = ["A","a","B","b"]
def main():
    test = input()
    if validate(test):
        print("Entered " + val)
    else:
        print("Did not enter a valid value")

def validate(val):
    if val in choice:
        return val
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one liner

```
def validate(val):
    return val in choice
```

and you could do something like this:

```
test = inputFromUser()

print validate(test) and "Entered " + test or "Did not enter a valid value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using following and see if it works for you ?

```
def validate(val):
    if val in choice
         return True
    return False
```

returning `False` explicitly to be very clear about what the function does, you can live without that